# Why calling shared_from_this calls std::terminate

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, c++17, std

Consider this code:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
     std::shared_ptr<A> f()
     {
          return shared_from_this();
     }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = a.f();
}
```

This code terminated in Visual Studio 2017. I guess I am doing something wrong here. Can anyone help me with this? I want a shared_ptr on a created by shared_from_this().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `a` is not a owned by a shared pointer. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this):

> **It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object,** i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17)std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the shared_ptr constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since C++17).

Comment: It's subtle, but the wording here also highlights that you can't use `shared_from_this` in the constructor, because until the object has been constructed it can't be managed by a shared_ptr

Comment: "_until the object has been constructed it can't be managed_" ...by any smart pointer. Not only that, until the object has been constructed, you don't know if it will be constructed or if construction will fail with an exception. If so, the destructors of the already constructed subobjects will be run, and no smart pointer will ever manage the object. So you can't even prepare the smart pointer in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `shared_from_this` to generate a *new* shared pointer. You already have to have an existing shared pointer to get a new one:

```
std::shared_ptr a(new A());
auto ptr = a->f(); // ok, 'ptr' shares ownership of newed object with 'a'
```

Comment: "_You cannot_" and it would be catastrophic if you could!

Answer (score 0):

## The issue is fundamental in the design (not technical details)

Whatever the exact specification of that C++ standard version you are using, what you are trying to do is impossible. Knowing the fine details of the specification of `shared_from_this` isn't needed to conclude that the code contains a design contradiction: *just understanding the intent, which is to obtain a `shared_ptr<A>` to `this`, inside a member function called on `a`, an automatic object, is enough to determine that the design is in error.*

In fact, any attempt at making an **owning smart pointer** (incl. but not limited to `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`) that points to (that owns) an object with "scoped" lifetime, that is an object whose lifetime is defined by the scope of the declaration of the object and ended by exiting something:

- automatic objects (lifetime ends when exiting the scope),
- namespace scope objects, static object members of classes (lifetime ends at program exit),
- non static members of classes (lifetime ends when the body of the destructor of the containing class object exits),

is a design error, because the:

- these objects were not created with any variant `new` (plain `operator new` or `nothrow` variant) that permits the call of `delete` on the result);
- the only case where C++ allows you to destroy such object is by destruction followed (preferably immediately) by reconstruction with placement new of an object with the same complete type, which is obviously not the job of an owning smart pointer;
- the compiler will destroy that object when program execution reach the exit point (exits scope, exits destructor, or `std::exit`, or `return` from main), no matter what (even if your owning smart pointer already took care of it); trying to destroy an already destroy object is not OK.

This includes constructing a smart pointer that owns (i.e. that promises to `delete`) a member of a class instance that was dynamically allocated:

```
struct A {
    int m;
};

#define OK 1

void f() {
    A *p = new A;
#if OK            
    std::shared_ptr<A> own (p); // fine
#else
    std::shared_ptr<int> own (&p->m); // bad
#endif
}
```

Here the lifetime of the object pointed to by `p` is managed dynamically; the timing of the destruction of determined explicitly, by program code, and the lifetime of the unique member `m` is intrinsically linked to the lifetime of the `A` object; but the member itself need not be destructed explicitly and shall not be deleted. If the `OK` preprocessor constant is 1, all is well; if it is 0, you are trying to manage explicitly the lifetime of a member, which is unsound.

About the term "explicit" call to `delete`: although th `delete` operator never appears in the code, its call is implicit on the use of `std::shared_ptr`; in other words, `std::shared_ptr` explicitly uses `delete`, so use of `std::shared_ptr` (or other similar owning smart pointers) are indirect use of `delete`.

## Safely sharing ownership with a smart pointer

**The only safe way to share ownership of a `shared_ptr` is to make one from another `shared_ptr`, directly, or indirectly.** This is the fundamental property of `shared_ptr`: all instances pointing to the one object must be traceable back to the one instance that one constructed with a raw pointer (or alternatively with `make_shared`).

This is a direct consequence of the fact that the ownership information (usually a reference count, but could be a linked list if you love inefficient implementations) is *not* inside the managed object, but inside the information block created by `shared_ptr`. This is not a property of just `std::shared_ptr`, it's a fact of life of all these externally managed objects, without a global registry, it's impossible to find the manager.

The basic design decision of these smart pointer is that the managed object need not be modified to use a smart pointer; hence they can be used on existing data type (incl. fundamental types).

## Importance of weak copies of a shared owning manager

The fundamental property of `shared_ptr` would create an issue: as every layer of code (that might need to call a function that needs an owning pointer) needs to keep a copy of the `shared_ptr` around, this can create a web of owning smart pointers, some of which might reside in an object whose lifetime is managed by another who lifetime is managed by that exact smart pointer; because the smart pointer basic specification is that the managed object is not destructed before all copies of the smart pointer in charge of its destruction are destroyed, these objects would never be destroyed (as specified; this is *not* a consequence of the particular implementation choice of reference counting). Sometimes a copy of a owning smart pointer of a specie that doesn't prevent influence the lifetime of the managed object is needed, hence the need for the weak smart pointer.

A (non null) weak smart pointer is always directly or indirectly a copy of an owning smart pointer, directly or indirectly a copy *the original* smart pointer that took ownership. That "weak reference" actually is a "strong" owning smart pointer to the information regarding the existence of other owning copies of the smart pointer: as long as there is a weak smart pointer, it will be possible to determine whether there is a live owning smart pointer, and if so to obtain a copy, that is make a shared smart pointer that an exact copy of *the original* (the lifetime of *the original* may have ended many generations of copies ago).

The only purpose of a weak smart pointer is to obtain such copies of *the original*.

## The purpose of `std::enable_shared_from_this`

The only use of `std::enable_shared_from_this` is to obtain a copy of *the original* `shared_ptr`; that implies that **such owning smart pointer must already exist**. No new original (another smart pointer taking ownership) will be made.

Only use `std::enable_shared_from_this` for classes that are only intended to be managed by a `shared_ptr`.

### Details of `std::enable_shared_from_this`

All that being said about the theoretical principles, it's useful to understand what `std::enable_shared_from_this` contains, how it can produce a `shared_ptr` when used correctly (and why it cannot be expected to work in any other case).

The "magic" of `std::enable_shared_from_this` may seem mysterious, and too magic so that users don't have to think about it, but it's actually extremely simple: it keeps a `weak_ptr` intended to be a copy of *the original*. Obviously it cannot be constructed as such copy, as *the original* cannot even be initialized when the `std::enable_shared_from_this` subobject is constructed: a valid owning smart pointer can only refer to a fully constructed object, because it owns it and is in charge of its destruction. [Even if by some cheating an owning smart pointer was made before the managed object was fully constructed, and hence destructible, the owning smart pointer would be a risk of premature destruction (even if during the normal course of events its lifetime is long, it could be shortened by an exception for example).]

So data member initialization in `std::enable_shared_from_this` is inherently default initialization: the "weak pointer" is null at that point.

Only when *the original* finally takes ownership if the managed object, it can *collude* with `std::enable_shared_from_this`: the constructing of *the original* `shared_ptr` will set once and for all the `weak_ptr` member inside `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Active collusion between these components is the only way to make the stuff work.

It's still the user's responsibility to only call `shared_from_this` only when it can possibly return a copy of *the original*, that is, after *the original* has been constructed.

## About fake (non owning) owning smart pointers

A fake owning smart pointer is one that does no cleanup ever: *owning smart pointer in name only*. They are special case of "owning" smart pointers used in such a way that no destruction or cleanup is performed. This ostensibly means that they could be used for objects whose lifetime is predetermined (and long enough) and for which there is a need to have a pretend owning smart pointer; unlike a real owning smart pointer, keeping a copy will not extend the lifetime of the object, so that lifetime should better be really long. (Because a copy of a owning smart pointer could be stored in a global variable, the object could still be expected to be alive after a `return` from `main`.)

These non owning owners are obviously a contradiction in the terms and rarely safe (but can be proven safe in a few cases).

They rarely solve a legitimate problem (one that isn't the immediate consequence of a very bad design): a `shared_ptr` in an interface means that the receiver is expecting to be able to extend the lifetime of the managed object.

Comment: Where did you take this material?

Comment: Which material? What do you mean?