# weak_from_this() within constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I know you can't use `shared_from_this` from within a constructor. But is it ok to use the new `weak_from_this` from within a constructor? According to cppreference:

> This is a copy of the the private mutable weak_ptr member that is part
>   of enable_shared_from_this.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/weak_from_this

I don't see an issue in obtaining a copy of the internally stored weak_ptr from within the constructor, but I might be missing something, so I'm not sure on this.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: **By definition of `weak_ptr`**, it's actually a duplicate of the question "Why calling shared_from_this calls std::terminate
" See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50302557/963864

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call it, but the `weak_ptr` will usually just be empty.

The point of `shared_from_this` is not to just make some `shared_ptr`, but to get a `shared_ptr` which shares ownership with the set of existing `shared_ptr` pointers.  And the point of `weak_ptr` is to provide a way of getting a `shared_ptr` which shares ownership if other `shared_ptr` pointers exist at the time, without extending the lifetime like directly storing a `shared_ptr` would.  So if no `shared_ptr` pointers to the object exist, a `weak_ptr` can't point at the same object.

Note that in normal use, when you do something like

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p(new MyClass);
```

the sequence is:

1. The implementation calls `operator new(sizeof(MyClass))` to get some storage.
2. The implementation calls a constructor of `MyClass` to create an object within that storage.

   - If `MyClass` inherits a specialization of
     `std::enable_shared_from_this`, it contains a `std::weak_ptr`
     subobject.  The default constructor of `weak_ptr` is used to create
     an empty smart pointer.
3. The implementation calls a constructor of `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>` to create a smart pointer, passing the pointer to the `MyClass` object.

   - The constructor of `shared_ptr` checks for whether the pointer points at a class type that inherits a compatible `std::enable_shared_from_this` specialization.  If it does, the `std::weak_ptr` subobject within the class object is reassigned to be a copy of the `shared_ptr` being constructed.

So within the constructor of `MyClass`, you'd be within step 2. But the internal pointer used by `shared_from_this()` and `weak_from_this()` doesn't become useful until step 3.

[A similar reassignment of the `weak_ptr` happens during `std::make_shared` and `std::allocate_shared`.  In those cases, the Standard doesn't obviously say that the `weak_ptr` is assigned after the complete pointed-at object is created, but it would be very unusual and unexpected for an implementation to go to extra effort to somehow magically do something to the `weak_ptr` at some point in between constructing the `enable_shared_from_this` base subobject and executing the derived class constructor body.]

It's possible you could create a `std::shared_ptr` which points at `this` from within a class constructor, to store it in some other variable or container or something.  (But if using the default deleter, make sure you somehow know the object was actually created with scalar `new`!)  After that point, both `shared_from_this()` and `weak_from_this()` can be used within the constructor and will return something connected to the already-created `std::shared_ptr`.  But this seems rather inside-out from the normal way of doing things.

Comment: "_you could create a std::shared_ptr which points at this from within a class constructor_" If the constructor throws, then boom!

Comment: I understand that the copied weak_ptr will be empty initially. The problem was that I didn't understand how weak_ptr's actually worked. I thought that a copy of a weak_ptr, even if it's empty at first, would become valid once the original weak_ptr becomes valid also. As if both weak_ptr had a reference to the same pointer, that might be **nullptr** initially, but would become valid at some point, and all weak_ptr's referencing this pointer would become valid also. As it seems, that's not how they work.